# How to access or format on doing any operation on volgroupharddisk on Fedora 13?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, logical-drive

I had only Fedora 13 on my Dell Inspiron 1545. I found that there is a harddisk named volgroup in my computer & one another disk on which Linux is installed.

The problem is that I can't access that space of my harddisk. It cannot be mounted. So please help me to geting access that or format it, because no options work on that.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux))

You do not mount a partition of type "Linux LVM" the same way you mount a partition using a standard Linux file system (e.g. ext2, ext3).
First, let's determine the volume group containing the physical volume.

```
# pvs
PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
/dev/hda2  VolGroup01 lvm2 a-   148.94G 32.00M
/dev/hdb2  VolGroup00 lvm2 a-   114.94G 96.00M
```

Next, let's list the logical volumes in VolGroup01.

```
# lvdisplay /dev/VolGroup01
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VolGroup01/LogVol00
  VG Name                VolGroup01
  LV UUID                zOQogm-G8I7-a4WC-T7KI-AhWe-Ex3Y-JVzFcR
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                146.97 GB
  Current LE             4703
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     0
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VolGroup01/LogVol01
  VG Name                VolGroup01
  LV UUID                araUBI-4eer-uh5L-Dvnr-3bI6-4gYg-APgYy2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                1.94 GB
  Current LE             62
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     0
  Block device           253:3
```

The logical volume I would like to "mount" (in purely the computing-related sense) is /dev/VolGroup01/LogVol00. The other logical volume is a swap partition.

```
# mount /dev/VolGroup01/LogVol00 /tmp/mnt
```